# How to pass object in method webview.Invokescript()?

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-metro

(Windows 8 Metro app) 
I have a HTML file in which I have an JavaScript function like

```
<script type="text/javascript">function somefunction(myobject) {
var myForm = document.forms[0];
myForm.num.value = myobject.getadd();
myForm.ans.value = myobject.getMul();
}
```

where order is an object of some class which has the methods like `getadd()`, `getMul()` etc
Problem Is..
 `WebView.InvokeScript()`-- Method can only have strings.
 I have to pass object so that I can do some computations..

Any best way...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass objects by sending their Json serialization: the javascript invoked is able to deserialize them easily.

What you cannot do is pass an object and have javascript call its methods, though.